# How to use a property within the server's JSON response object (instead of full object) to populate a Kendo grid?

Tags: jquery, json, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have the following kendo grid:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        url: "customers",
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json"
                    }
                },
                height: 550,
                columns: [{
                    field: "contactName",
                    title: "Contact Name",
                    width: 240
                }, {
                    field: "contactTitle",
                    title: "Contact Title"
                }, {
                    field: "companyName",
                    title: "Company Name"
                }, {
                    field: "country",
                    width: 150
                }]
            });
```

The JSON response from the server looks like:

```
{
   "date": "2020-02-02",
   "responseType": "customer contact",
   "customerContact": [{
        "contactName": "Bob Smith",
        "contactTitle": "Manager",
        "companyName": "Acme",
        "country": "Canada"
    },{ 
    //more customerContact data
   }]
}
```

The grid is trying to populate using this full JSON object. How can I tell it to use only the `customerContact` property within the object?

I also need to get the `date` and `responseType` from the response to populate an HTML element outside the grid using:

```
$("#title").append('<h3>' + response.reponseType + ' at ' + date + '</h3>');
```

How can I pull out the `responseType` and `date` to populate the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `schema.data` property to indicate that your data isn't at the response root. You can use the `requestEnd` event to access the response directly, and populate your title element. See the [dataSource documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource) for more info.

```
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    url: "customers",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                schema: {
                    data: "customerContact"
                },
                requestEnd: function(e) {
                    if (e.type === "read" && e.response) {
                        $("#title").append('<h3>' + e.response.reponseType + ' at ' + e.response.date + '</h3>');
                    }
                }
            },
            height: 550,
            columns: [{
                field: "contactName",
                title: "Contact Name",
                width: 240
            }, {
                field: "contactTitle",
                title: "Contact Title"
            }, {
                field: "companyName",
                title: "Company Name"
            }, {
                field: "country",
                width: 150
            }]
        });
```